# Can I trigger same AWS lambda from multiple SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to trigger a lambda function from multiple SQS queues. Most of the processing the lambda will do is same, just one small step will be based on the table name. I don't want to maintain two separate lambda for that. What's the pros and cons of having same/multiple lambda?

Comment: Having different Lambda functions allows you to configure them differently, for example their per-function concurrency limits. That may or may not be an advantage to you, but it's something to consider if this is a high concurrency system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there's no reason you can't configure it that way. It should work fine.